# Realtime Image shift from camera

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, android

I'm searching for a method that can provide instanly to me the image shift using the front camera as image source.

So the front camera will be always active, when I move the smartphone I Should obtains the image displacement based on frames instanly captured by the camera.

Does It could be done using the image registration algorithm or something like It? It Should be instant

Comment: Did you tried `onPreviewFrame`  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.PreviewCallback.html  ?.

Comment: I didn't Tried an implementation...this could be istantly but I don't know if the image registration algorithm, applied in each frame, is instanly too

Answer (score 1):

It needs to process camera preview as mentioned @sunil sunny. Image registration is expensive to be instant, therefore optical flow tracking would be good option. Also it needs OpenCV to be instant.

1. [Background subtraction](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d1/dc5/tutorial_background_subtraction.html)

   - This method detects moving parts
   - If camera is moved, most part of camera preview will be changed
   - Therefore, this method can be used to detect whether camera is moved or not
2. [Optical flow](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_lucas_kanade.html)

   - This method is fast
   - You can get translations (x, y) of each pixel
   - If background is stationary and the camera is the only moving object, this method will gives image translation by averaging (or similar) all translations